# Pass var name as "String"

Tags: python

Is there a way to pass "GENDER" attach it to `QuestionFocus` and then get what's behind `QuestionFocus.GENDER`? I could of course just pass `QuestionFocus.GENDER` but it would make it longer than (maybe) necessary.

```
def get_answers(question_focus):
    return Answer.objects.filter(
        response_id__in=get_super_guests().values_list("id", flat=True),
        question__focus=QuestionFocus.question_focus,
    ).order_by("-created")

context["genders"] = get_answers("GENDER")
```

Comment: `QuestionFocus.GENDER` looks way better to me, because a good linter will detect if someone by mistake requests something that doesn't exist, like `get_answers('GENDR')`

Comment: Okay, yes that's a good argument.